Como insertar datos de una lista que trae multiple registros a un query en Java de una sola vez y no uno por uno?
Tengo un metodo leerDatos que se encarga de obtener los datos de una tabla y los va guardando en una lista, pero lo hago como por bloques, ya que la tabla contiene multiples datos, lo que quiero hacer es que esos datos que fui obteniendo y guardadando en la lista se inserten en otra tabla, para ello hice el metodo insertarDatos que mando a llamar dentro del metodo leerDatos para pasarle la lista, pero al ejecutarlo manda el siguiente error

SQL Error: La consulta no retornó ningún resultado.

y si consulto la tabla solo tiene agregado un regstro, si vuelvo a correr la aplicacion manda lo mismo y vuelve a insertar solo un registro
lo que queiro hacer es que inserte todos los datos de la lista de una sola vez, alguien podria ayudarme a hacerlo y saber que es lo que tengo mal
public void leerDatos() {
        String user = "postgres";
        String pss = "admin123";

        empleadoList = new ArrayList<>();
        Empleados empleado = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        PreparedStatement stm = null;
        Connection connect = null;

        final int pageSize = 100000; // Tamaño de cada página
        int offset = 0;
        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd_test", user, pss);
            PreparedStatement stmCount = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) from empleados");
            ResultSet resultCount = stmCount.executeQuery();
            int records = 0;

            while (resultCount.next()) {
                records = resultCount.getInt(1);
            }
            System.out.println("Total de registros:  " + records);
            
            
            // Leer datos por páginas
            while (offset < records) {
                System.out.println("SE CUMPLE ENTRA AL 1 WHILE :  ");
                String query = "SELECT * FROM empleados LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
                stm = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                stm.setInt(1, pageSize);
                stm.setInt(2, offset);
                result = stm.executeQuery();
                while (result.next()) {
                    empleado = new Empleados();
                    empleado.setNombre(result.getString("nombre"));
                    empleado.setApellido(result.getString("apellido"));
                    empleado.setSalario(result.getString("salario"));
                    empleadoList.add(empleado);
                }

                offset += pageSize; // Se incrementa el offset para la siguiente página
                System.out.println("OFFSET  :  " + offset);
            }
            if (!empleadoList.isEmpty()) {
                
                System.out.println("Primer nombre en la lista: " + empleadoList.get(0).getNombre());
                insertarDatos(empleadoList);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("SQL Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (result != null) {
                    result.close();
                }
                if (stm != null) {
                    stm.close();
                }
                if (connect != null) {
                    connect.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("SQL Error en cierre: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

public void insertarDatos(List<Empleados> empleList) throws SQLException {
        
        
        ResultSet result = null;
        String user = "postgres";
        String pss = "admin123";
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd_test", user, pss);
        PreparedStatement stm = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO empleados_duplicado (nombre_dup, apellido_dup, salario_dup) VALUES (?,?,?)");

        for (Empleados empl : empleList) {
            stm.setString(1, empl.getNombre());
            stm.setString(2, empl.getApellido());
            stm.setString(3, empl.getSalario());

        }
        stm.executeQuery();//executeBatch();

    }


El error que noto inicialmente es que dentro de insertarDatos() hay un bucle, pero no estás insertando los datos:
public void insertarDatos(List<Empleados> empleList) throws SQLException {                        
        ResultSet result = null;
        String user = "postgres";
        String pss = "admin123";
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd_test", user, pss);
        PreparedStatement stm = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO empleados_duplicado (nombre_dup, apellido_dup, salario_dup) VALUES (?,?,?)");

        for (Empleados empl : empleList) {
            stm.setString(1, empl.getNombre());
            stm.setString(2, empl.getApellido());
            stm.setString(3, empl.getSalario());
            //* Se recorre el bucle pero no se insertan datos
        }
        stm.executeQuery();//executeBatch();
    }

En este caso usa mejor executeBatch(), que veo lo trataste de usar,  además de usar addBatch():

executeBatch(): devuelve una matriz de números enteros, y cada
elemento de la matriz representa el recuento de actualizaciones para
la declaración de actualización respectiva.
addBatch(): de Statement, PreparedStatement y CallableStatement se
utiliza para agregar declaraciones individuales al lote.
EjecutarBatch() se utiliza para iniciar la ejecución de todas las
declaraciones agrupadas.

realiza el cambio siguiente, no olvidando cerrar la conexión y el PreparedStatement :
public void insertarDatos(List<Empleados> empleList) throws SQLException {                        
        ResultSet result = null;
        String user = "postgres";
        String pss = "admin123";
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd_test", user, pss);
        PreparedStatement stm = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO empleados_duplicado (nombre_dup, apellido_dup, salario_dup) VALUES (?,?,?)");

        for (Empleados empl : empleList) {
            stm.setString(1, empl.getNombre());
            stm.setString(2, empl.getApellido());
            stm.setString(3, empl.getSalario());            
            stm.addBatch(); //*
        }
        stm.executeBatch(); //*


        stm.close(); 
        connect.close(); 

    }

